# AmChart: Adding Guide column when exporting a chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a Line AmChart where I tag a specific amount of data with a guide. I want to export the guide as a column when exporting the entire data.

For example,

`date    visits
14/10/2017  36
15/10/2017  40
16/10/2017  39
17/10/2017  41
18/10/2017  36
19/10/2017  32
20/10/2017  33
21/10/2017  54
22/10/2017  60
23/10/2017  48
24/10/2017  56
25/10/2017  72
26/10/2017  72
27/10/2017  39
28/10/2017  58
29/10/2017  69
30/10/2017  75
31/10/2017  66
01/11/2017  45`

I have managed to add Guides dynamically and add a string to it.

[image]

I want to export the data that looks like this:

`date    visits
14/10/2017  36
15/10/2017  40
16/10/2017  39
17/10/2017  41
18/10/2017  36
19/10/2017  32 tag1
20/10/2017  33 tag1
21/10/2017  54 tag1
22/10/2017  60 tag1
23/10/2017  48 tag1
24/10/2017  56
25/10/2017  72
26/10/2017  72
27/10/2017  39 tag2
28/10/2017  58 tag2
29/10/2017  69 tag2
30/10/2017  75 tag2
31/10/2017  66
01/11/2017  45`

Code is found in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryjoy2pp/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guides aren't considered as data as they aren't part of the chart `dataProvider` array, so they won't get exported in any of the data formats by default. In order to get the guides included in the data export, you have to add the guide text to the `dataProvider`. Here's a very basic modification to your `selected` listener that handles it:

```
chart.chartCursor.addListener("selected", function(event) {
    // guide setup omitted
    var cursor = event.startIndex;

    while (cursor <= event.endIndex) {
      chart.dataProvider[cursor]["guide"] = text;
      ++cursor;
    }
    //add guide/validate omitted
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryjoy2pp/1/)

Comment: That was a smart solution! Thanks.